# how to do this function in one line

Tags: python

Is it possible to do this code in one line.
I tried it with a lambda funcion and python for loop one liner and Im not able to do it.
The problem in for one liner is to make the break point in the loop, returning True.

```
self.exists = False
for value in self.dict_times.values():
    if value!= 0: 
        self.exists = True
        break
```

Comment: `self.exists = any(value != 0 for value in self.dict_items.values())`

Comment: try to see if `any()` would work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Paul M.**
This one works perfect.

```
self.exists = any(value != 0 for value in self.dict_items.values())
```

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, use `any()`:

```
self.exists = any(self.dict_times.values())
```

Comment: This solution doesn't include the handling of `None` values, but in most cases this should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR `any(1 for val in values if val != 0)`

---

As many have already told you, both in comments and answers, `any()` is the way to go.

`any` doc string says

```
In [13]: any?
Signature: any(iterable, /)
Docstring:
Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

If the iterable is empty, return False.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

but it fails to mention that `any` is a *short-circuit* operator, that stops the iteration as soon as one of the tests evaluates to true, so that your requirement about **breaking** the loop is satisfied by `any`.

Let's check that for a sequence of 0 and 1 `any` does the right thing

```
In [14]: any((0,0,1,0,1))
Out[14]: True
```

instead of a sequence the argument of `any` can be also a generator, this helps us to show that we have a short circuiting indeed

```
In [15]: any((print(val) or val) for val in (0,0,1,0,1))
0
0
1
Out[15]: True
```

as you can see, the last `print` that is evaluated is associated with the first one and we skip the last two items in `(0,0,1,0,1)`.

Now, what happens if we interpret *strictly* your test `value != 0` ?

```
In [16]: any((print(val) or val) for val in (0,0,None,0,0))
0
0
None
0
0
Out[16]: False

In [17]: None != 0
Out[17]: True
```

So, if we are serious about `value != 0`, we have to write

```
In [18]: any(1 for val in (0,0,None,0,0) if (print(val) or val) != 0)
0
0
None
Out[18]: True
```

What happens if your sequence contains a boolean?  to answer, let's see the results of the test

```
In [19]: False != 0, True != 0
Out[19]: (False, True)

In [20]: any(1 for val in (0,False) if (print(val) or val) != 0)
0
False
Out[20]: False
```

So, if we want to stay with Python semantics, that's it, if we want to stress the fact that `False` is not zero, well, there is the `is not` logical test that *in this specific case* (checking with zero) works because in CPython at least (the most common interpreter) small integers are cached

```
In [21]: any(1 for val in (0,False) if (print(val) or val) is not 0)
<>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
<ipython-input-21-062bcd4ba4c9>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  any(1 for val in (0,False) if (print(val) or val) is not 0)
0
False
Out[21]: True
```

so, it works but we have that nasty `SyntaxWarning` ... but it's easy to fix

```
In [22]: z = 0

In [23]: any(1 for val in (0,False) if (print(val) or val) is not z)
0
False
Out[23]: True
```

but probably this last expression is overdone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
`self.exists = bool(sum(self.dict_times.values()))`

Comment: this is not the way to go. no point summing booleans just to convert an int to bool.

Comment: this unnecessarily iterates over all values. `any` short-circuits and stops of a value is found.

Comment: The OP says _"The problem [for a] one liner is **to make the break point** in the loop"_, otoh your solution evaluates all the logical tests.